# Protostar, linux Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'

Tags: linux, debian

I want to do the Protostar exploit exercises in https://exploit-exercises.lains.space/

I wanted to install the Python 3 version and to do that I need to run the sudo apt-get update command. But it seems like it fails and the problem is with the dns. But unfortunately I can't fix it.

This is the output when I run the command.

```
root@protostar:/etc# sudo apt-get update
sudo: unable to resolve host protostar
Err http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en     
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_US  
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://www.remastersys.com squeeze/ Release.gpg                     
  Could not resolve 'www.remastersys.com'
Err http://www.remastersys.com/repository/ squeeze/ Translation-en      
  Could not resolve 'www.remastersys.com'
Err http://www.remastersys.com/repository/ squeeze/ Translation-en_US   
  Could not resolve 'www.remastersys.com'
Err http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze Release.gpg                        
  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'
Err http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en
  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'
Err http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'
Err http://ftp.au.debian.org squeeze-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'
Err http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en
  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'
Err http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'ftp.au.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://www.remastersys.com/repository/squeeze/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'www.remastersys.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://www.remastersys.com/repository/squeeze/en.bz2  Could not resolve 'www.remastersys.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://www.remastersys.com/repository/squeeze/en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'www.remastersys.com'

W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I fix it to run sudo apt-get update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve and download python 3.6 on Protostar :

( apparently there was no internet connection on the host because of the Host-only adapter in virtualbox )

downloaded python using wget :

> wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.9/Python-3.6.9.tgz

Then I transferred it using scp ( ssh ) ( you can move it to /tmp and then to /usr/sbin if it says no permission )

> scp Python-3.6.9.tgz root@192.168.56.102:/usr/sbin

exported and install python

```
 tar xvf Python-3.6.9.tgzls
 ./configure
 sudo make install
```

and lastly :

> alias python=/usr/sbin/Python-3.6.9/python